# object syntax confusion for functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, syntax

I ran across some syntax on the react meteor example that confused me. I asked two JS devs that I know and they could only provide guesses. Can anyone explain why this works?

```
var aaa = {
   bbb() {
      // do something
   }
};

aaa.bbb();
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/k15bd6pj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's ES2015 shorthand notation. This:

```
var obj = { property() { /* code */ } };
```

is equivalent to ES5

```
var obj = { property: function property() { /* code */ } };
```

The new syntax works in newer browsers (or Node), or via something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Wow, approved in July, huh? Guess I need to stay more current on the news... Thanks!